# R - manipulate a table

Tags: r

I have a table with the following structure (see picture)[image: table]

You may see that sometimes in V3 are multiple words, separated by ",". They are linked to a score (which you can see in V2). Is it possible to put every word on a new row and transfer the score aswell to the new row?

Thank you!

I was able to manipulate the table manually. But I am looking for a code which does this automatically.

Answer (score 2):

Check `sep_longer_delim()` with `delim = ","` like so:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(
  V1 = "Abschluß|NN",
  V2 = 0.004,
  V3 = "Abschluss,Abschlüsse,Abschlussen"
)

df |> 
  separate_longer_delim(V3, delim = ",")
#> # A tibble: 3 × 3
#>   V1             V2 V3         
#>   <chr>       <dbl> <chr>      
#> 1 Abschluß|NN 0.004 Abschluss  
#> 2 Abschluß|NN 0.004 Abschlüsse 
#> 3 Abschluß|NN 0.004 Abschlussen
```

<sup>Created on 2023-04-11 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>